# How I can click on the element array?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have two arrays, one - full elements(filterList), two - empty(addList). When I click on the first element (full array) it's added to second array (empty array). How I can click on the element (title:'DATA') ?

```
<ul class="flex">
<li class="text-white text-xs uppercase font-normal not-italic px-2 py-1.75 mr-3 border border-gray-900 border-solid rounded-xs transition duration-500 hover:cursor-pointer hover:border-purple hover:bg-black-700" 
  v-for="(item, index) of addList" 
  :item="item" 
  :key="index"
  @click="testClick()"
  >
<span class="flex items-center">{{item.title}} <IconCheckMark class="stroke-white ml-2.25"/></span>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="border border-purple rounded-md p-2.5 inline-block min-w-35.25 bg-black-900 absolute z-110 max-h-64 overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden">
<li 
   v-for="(item, index) of filterList" 
   :item="item" 
   :key="index"
class="text-xs text-white uppercase py-1.5 px-2.5 hover:bg-black-700 hover:rounded-xs hover:cursor-pointer transition-all ease-in" @click="addFiltres(item)"
          >
            <span>{{item.title}}</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

```
addFiltres(item){
if (this.addList.indexOf(this.filterList) == this.addList.lastIndexOf(this.filterList)) {
this.addList.push(item)
}
this.addList = \[...new Set(this.addList)\]
},
testClick() {

      },

filterList: \[
{title: 'DATE', value: 'date'},
{title: 'TIME', value: 'time'},
{title: 'COLOR', value: 'color'},

        ],
        addList:[]
```

I try to solve this problem: 1) indexOf () 2) find() 3) includes(). Not work.

Comment: welcome to SO. Your question, as posted, is difficult to understand. Try to explain better what you want to achieve, what is the problem you have, what you tried, what you expected, what you got instead, and finally ask a specific question.

Comment: Also, you cannot use Vue 2 AND 3 at the same time. Please pick one or stick to the regular tag. No need to spam tags.

Comment: @kissu hi, I use Vue 3 and add tag Vue 3. Thank you for advice.

Comment: @PA. hi, I want to add click for element {title: 'TIME', value: 'time'}, array [empy], wich I add with push() method from array filteList.

Comment: edit your question following the tips that StackOverflow provides on how to post a correct question:  Summarize the problem,  Include details about your goal,  Describe expected and actual results,  Include any error messages.  Describe what you’ve tried. Show what you’ve tried and tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. You can get better answers when you provide research. And show some code, share the minimum amount of code others need to reproduce your problem (also called a minimum, reproducible example)